# Create huge text file - multi-threading a good idea?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, c++11

A need to create huge (>10 Gb) text files where every line is a very long number, basically a string as even types like `unsigned long long` won't be enough. So i will be using random generator and first though was that probably it's a good idea create several threads. From what I see, every thread will be writing one line at a time, which is considered a thread safe operation in C++.
Is it a good idea or am I missing something and it's better just to write line by line from one thread?

Comment: Bottle neck here is IO operations not CPU operations, so adding threads here is pointless.

Comment: you are writing using `<<` operator in `std::ofstream`?

Comment: Try it and you'll see performance crawl to a halt.

Comment: It would be good if you do profiling first to ensure that I didn't lied to you (first comment), it will be a good lesson for you.

Comment: Random Number: Not thread safe. Stream IO: Not thread safe. Writing to the same file is contentious (same resource) and will cause excessive blocking. How fast is your IO device? How many threads writing to the device before it can't keep up?

Comment: In a word... no.

Comment: Unless the documentations for it explicitly states something is thread safe, it won't be thread sate. Practically nothing in C++ is thread safe. Most of the time you don't need thread safety, so why pay the price for something you probably aren't using? Instead practically everything is relatively easy to wrap or otherwise protect with the tools in the [thread support library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: Even if you could guarantee the file I/O were thread-safe, the only sane way to have multiple threads writing different lines to a single file is if all of the lines are the same byte length. You could then pre-size the file at creation, then have each thread seek to the appropriate line offset and write its output without worrying about clobbering surrounding lines. But, if the lines are variable length, then this is not an option.

Comment: I advise against multiple threads for writing, however, I do recommend writing in blocks (the larger the better).  Usually one thread for writing one or more buffers to the file.  Other threads will write to the buffers.  For example, the GUI thread would fill buffer1 then start the "write" thread.  Next, the GUI thread writes to buffer 2 (while the "write" thread is writing from buffer1).  After the "write" thread finishes buffer 1, it starts on buffer 2.  Repeat.  Note, multiple buffers may be necessary to adjust for any blocking from full buffers.

Comment: Synchronizing threads writing to the same file is difficult.  Consider 5 threads that are writing to the file.  How does one ensure the ordering of the threads?  (Yes, this can be accomplished with mailboxes, but it gets complicated.)

Comment: Consider ACCU Overload - [5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf) (2nd Article)

Comment: You probably need to use a database, so try at least [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/), [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/), or [Redis](https://redis.io/)

Comment: @WARhead yes, with std::ofstream

Comment: @ThomasMatthews as it's just random I don't care about line ordering, just one full line should be in exact format, but the order doesn't matter a t all

Answer (score 3):

A correct answer here will depend fairly heavily on the type of drive to which you're writing the file.

If it's an actual hard drive, then a single thread will probably be able to generate your random numbers *and* write the data to the disk as fast as the disk can accept it. With reasonable code on a modern CPU, the core running that code will probably spend more time idle than it does doing actual work.

If it's a SATA hard SSD, effectively the same thing will be true, but (especially if you're using an older CPU) the core running the code will probably spend a lot less time idle. A single thread will probably still be able to generate the data and write it to the drive as fast as the drive can accept it.

Then we get to things like NVMe and Optane drives. Here you honestly might stand a decent chance of improving performance by writing from multiple threads. But (at least in my experience) to do that, you just about have to skip past using iostreams, and instead talk directly to the OS. Under Windows, that would mean opening the file with CreateFile (specifying FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED when you do). Windows also has built in support for  [I/O completion ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) (which are really sort of thread pools) to minimize overhead and improve performance--but using it is somewhat nontrivial.

On Linux, asynchronous I/O is a bit more of a sore point. There's an official AIO interface for doing asynchronous I/O, and Linux has had an implementation of that for a long time, but it's never really worked very well. More recently, something called `io_uring` was added to the Linux kernel. I haven't used it a lot, but it looks like it's probably a better design--but it doesn't (as far as I know) support the standard AIO interface, so you pretty much have to use via its own [`liburing`](https://github.com/axboe/liburing) instead. Rather that Windows I/O completion ports, this works well, but using it is somewhat non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no explicit synchronization between the threads, you need to make sure that the library functions you use are thread-safe. For example, the C++ random number generators in <random> are not, so it would be best to have one RNG per thread. Additionally, you need to look at bottlenecks. Conversion of a number to text is one bottleneck, and multithreading would help with that. Output is another, and multithreading would not. Profiling would help resolve this.

Ostreams are not thread-safe, so you'll have to use synchronization to protect each thread's access.